# No "Script Area" in Lotus Notes Agent editor

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I need the functionality described here: [Determining which folder contains a document in Lotus Notes without using the LotusScript FolderReferences property](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295618)

It says: "And the following code in the Script Area". But there's no script area. There's a tree containing "Document Selection", "(Options)", "Declarations", "Initialize", and , "Terminate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter that code into the body of the Initialize method. Make sure to keep the code that automatically appears when you select Initialize and just enter the code in the middle

```
Sub Initialize

    Dim session As New notessession
    Dim db As notesdatabase
    Dim doc As notesdocument
    Dim doc2 As notesdocument
    Dim view As notesview
    Dim noteid1 As String
    Dim noteid2 As String
    Dim item As notesitem
    Dim collection As notesdocumentcollection
    Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
    Set collection=db.UnprocessedDocuments
    Set doc=collection.getfirstdocument
    noteid1=doc.NoteID
    Forall v In db.Views

        If v.isfolder Then
          Set doc2=v.GetFirstDocument
          While Not doc2 Is Nothing
            noteid2=doc2.NoteID
            If noteid1=noteid2 Then
                Messagebox v.name
            End If
            Set doc2=v.getnextdocument(doc2)
          Wend
        End If

    End Forall

End Sub
```